# How does angular change variables that are bound to event listeners

Tags: angularjs

I'm a ruby dev by trade and new to angular. I've been following many guides but I would appreciate any help in solving this problem. I understand angular has this idea of lazy loading, but I'm not sure how that fits in with my scenario. The app I am making consists of a login screen which posts to the server your credentials. the server responds with a jwt signed token to be used for socket connections.

For simplicity, I have 2 controllers, `LoginCtrl`, and `HomeCtrl`. And I have the factory called `signaling`

Here is what the HomeCtrl looks like:

```
angular.module('myApp')

.controller('HomeCtrl',function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, $http, config, signaling){

  $scope.homeDo = function () {
    signaling.socket.emit("ping","nothing")

  };
  signaling.socket.on("pong", function(m){
    console.log("it worked!");
  })

});
```

Now `signaling` uses socketFactory to create a socket. My question first starts off with this: I want the user's socket connection to be created with a token they receive via posting to the server.. How do I create that socket connection with the token NOT at run time. Here's the signaling factory code:

```
angular.module('myApp')

.factory('signaling', function(socketFactory,$localStorage, config, $state,$ionicPopup) {

  this.token = {};
  this.socket = socketFactory({ioSocket: io.connect(config.api+'/?token=' + this.token, { 'forceNew': true})})

  return this;
  }
});
```

As you can see, signaling's token is not set when the app first runs. The socket attempts to connect with an undefined token parameter. I don't want this. I want to explicitly set the token for the factory, and then create the socket only when I have been successfully signed in.

Here is my LoginCtrl code:

```
angular.module('myApp')

.controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, $http, config, socketFactory, signaling, $localStorage){
 $scope.data = {};
 $scope.login = function () {
    $http.post(config.api+'/login',{
    username: $scope.data.username,
    password: $scope.data.password})
    .success(function(data, status, headers) {
      signaling.token = data.token;
      signaling.socket = socketFactory({ioSocket: io.connect(config.api+'/?token=' + data.token, { 'forceNew': true})})
      $state.go('app.home');
     })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $state.go('app.login');
    });
  };    
});
```

Now let's say I hit the success callback after logging in and I get the token. signaling.socket IS now the correct socket I want to use, however now all the even listeners are not setup to listen on it. For example, earlier in the `HomeCtrl` code, I had the listener:

```
signaling.socket.on("pong", function(m){
  console.log("it worked!");
})
```

That code will not be executed if the server emits "pong" because I suspect that when the app first ran. signaling.socket was the socket created with the undefined token. I have verified this by manually adding the correct token.

I understand that I probably should go back and hit the books and read up more on Angular, however I just can't get my head to wrap around this.

TL;DR - 
I have an object (signaling) which has an instance variable `socket` I want to set the `socket` variable to something NOT at runtime, however at runtime, I register event listeners on the null signaling.socket. I want to either re-register the events, or NOT run `HomeCtrl` at runtime..

Anyway I know that was a huge block of text, If there are any kind souls willing to read this I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you can't run `HomeCtrl` at runtime, you can add `signaling.socket` to `HomeCtrl` scope's watch list and monitor its change, like below

```
$scope.$watch('signaling.socket', function(socket) {
  if (socket) {
    socket.on("pong", function(m){
      console.log("it worked!");
    });
  }
});
```

This way, when you create a new socket with token in `LoginCtrl`, `HomeCtrl` will catch this change and bind the handler `pong` to to the newly created socket.

If users are not allowed to view home page unless they are logged in, there is a better solution

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state, signaling) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      if (toState === 'home' && !!signaling.token) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
      }
      $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
    }
}
```

Then `HomeCtrl` will be initialized only after the token exists, and `signaling.socket` can be created just once.

Comment: WOW... I was not expecting such a solid and helpful reply!! I can't thank you enough.. This was very helpful and solved many problems. I did have to change quite a bit of code in the app.run code (ran into an infinite loop) but other than that this helped quite a bit. :)